# Redefining ENTER key in Emacs

Tags: emacs, scala

I don't know elisp, but I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
(add-hook
 'scala-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (define-key scala-mode-map (kbd "RET") (lambda ()
                                            (scala-newline)
                                            (scala-indent-line)))))
```

Goal is to call the two functions each time I hit the ENTER key. How do I actually do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need an `(interactive)` form after the `lambda` in your `define-key`.

**EDIT:**

To be clear, the inner form should look like:

```
(lambda ()
  (interactive)
  (scala-newline)
  (scala-indent-line))
```

Answer (score 8):

I do essentially this in so many modes that I've squashed them all together:

```
(mapcar (lambda (hooksym)
          (add-hook hooksym
                    (lambda ()
                      (local-set-key  (kbd "C-m") 'newline-and-indent)
                      )))
        '(
          clojure-mode-hook
          emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          erlang-mode-hook
          java-mode-hook
          js-mode-hook
          lisp-interaction-mode-hook
          lisp-mode-hook
          makefile-mode-hook
          nxml-mode-hook
          python-mode-hook
          ruby-mode-hook
          scheme-mode-hook
          sh-mode-hook
          ))
```

Just stick `scala-mode-hook` in there somewhere and it'll work for you too :)

Answer (score 2):

In hook you can use local-set-key, for example

```
(add-hook 'scala-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (local-set-key [return] 
        (lambda ()
            (scala-newline)
            (scala-indent-line)))))
```

although, maybe it will be easier to use something like standard newline-and-indent?

```
(add-hook 'scala-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (local-set-key [return] 'newline-and-indent)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type <kbd>C-j</kbd> it will call the `newline-and-indent` command and do exactly what you ask.